# Adding tabs to asp.net content page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have many content pages. In master page I have added the tab About us, support, contact us. Which will come in all pages. But some pages will have different tabs from other pages. EX: group page will have users and message tab, users page will have groups tab and message tab. I can design this in master page as it varies from page to page. The tabs depends on the user permission, for each user it is going to change. What is the best way of doing this.

Comment: Are the views dependent on some kind of permissions?

Comment: Yes. For each user it is going to change

Comment: Style your tabs with CSS against a bullet list of links - add permission attributes to each link from an XML file... and take it from there :)

Answer (score 0):

As a general concept, I would develop the tabs as a user control or server control. The control should render its tabs based on the current user and the current page. If that's enough to get you started, great. If not, post a comment and I'll see if I can put together a sample for you.

Comment: Sample would help me. I am adding tab in each content page. which is not stable as it moves around when i zoom the browser. i know I am doing it wrong. pls help